# File upload using express nodejs multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to upload a file image with multer in express and file is uploading in the directory, but name of the file is not saving in database. I am using mongodb with express. Filename is saving as noimage.png.

routes/posts.js:-

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.files.mainimage){
    console.log('Uploading files...');

    // File Info
    var mainImageOriginalName = req.files.mainimage.originalname;
    var mainImageName = req.files.mainimage.name;
    var mainImageMime = req.files.mainimage.mimetype;
    var mainImagePath = req.files.mainimage.path;
    var mainImageExt = req.files.mainimage.extension;
    var mainImageSize = req.files.mainimage.size;
  }
  else{
    var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }
  //console.log(req.files.mainimage.name);

  // Check for errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('add', {
        errors: errors,
    });
  }
  else{
    var posts = db.get('posts');

    // Submit to db
    posts.insert({
        mainimage: mainImageName
    }, function(err, post){
        if(err){
            res.send('There was an issue submitting the post');
        }
        else{
            req.flash('success', 'Post Submitted');
            res.location('/posts');
            res.redirect('/posts');
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you save it to the DB with mainImageOriginalName instead of mainImageName (line 31)?

Comment: Actually, req.files.mainimage returns false. so, going in else block.

Comment: Have you tried req.file instead of req.files? Are you uploading one image or multiple ones? Can you post your full posts.js file so we can make sure your dependencies are right?

Comment: Yes, I have tried req.file, but not worked, thrown error as undefined property.

Comment: Is this on github or something so I can look at the whole project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **multer** it seems you didn't specify as multer's specification

```
router.post('/add', multer({ dest: './uploads/'}).single('myimage'), function(req,res){...})
```